# Check the status code of a scp command and if it is failed, then call scp on another machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scp

Below is my snippet of shell script in which I am executing scp command to copy the files from `machineB` to `machineA`.

```
for element in ${x[$key]}; do   # no quotes here
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "$element"
    if [ $key -eq 0 ]
    then
        scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_$element_5.data /data01/primary/.
    fi    
done
```

I have a very simple question which is mentioned below -

If the above scp command in my shell script gives me this error for whatever reason -  `No such file or directory`
then I need to try doing `scp` from `machineC` and for that scp command will be like this, only machine will be different and everything else will be same -

```
scp david@machineC:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_$element_5.data /data01/primary/.
```

So my question is how to check the output of the above scp command in my shell script and then decide whether I need to call scp command from machineC or not? Is there any status kind of thing which I can use to check and if it got failed for whatever reason, then I can call scp command on machineC?

Is this possible to do in shell script?

Comment: maybe rsync is the solution you are looking for. It helps you sync two directories, also over the network.

Comment: or Unison - I blogged about it: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Unison. It works non-graphically over the network, too (as you are asking for a shell script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for element in ${x[$key]}; do   # no quotes here
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "$element"
    if [ $key -eq 0 ]
    then
        scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_$element_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_$element_5.data /data01/primary/
    fi    
done
```

Well-behaving commands exit with "success" (exit code = 0) if the operation was successful, or otherwise with an exit code != 0. You can chain commands together like this:

```
cmd && echo successful || echo failed
cmd && keep going || do something else
```

The exit code is also stored in the `$?` variable, so this is equivalent:

```
cmd; if $? = 0; then echo successful; else echo failed; fi
```

Not only this is possible, the status code of commands is extremely important in shell scripting. Consider these two examples:

```
./configure && make && make install
./configure; make; make install
```

The first one will execute the chain of commands if all are successful. The second will execute all of them *always*, even if an earlier command failed.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. So you are saying if first scp command failed for whatever reason, then second scp command will be executed right? And if first scp command got executed successfully, then it won't execute second scp command?

Answer (score 1):

scp returns 0 only wen it succeeds.
so you can write like this:

```
scp machineB:/path/toyourfile .
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    scp machineC:/path/to/your/file .
fi
```

a shorter way is:

```
scp machineB:/path/toyourfile .
[ $? -eq 0 ] || scp machineC:/path/to/your/file .
```

or

```
scp machineB:/path/toyourfile .
[ $? -ne 0 ] && scp machineC:/path/to/your/file .
```

personally I prefer the even shorter way, and the scp output is of no use in script:

```
scp -q machineB:/path/to/your/file . || scp -q machineC:/path/to/your/file .
```

and remember to use `${element}` instead of `$element`